# map-invert with a tweak for a map whose values are sequences

Tags: clojure

How to invert a map whose values are sequences?
In the inverted map the keys are the entries of all the sequences (assuming no duplicate keys)

For instance:

```
(map-invert-tweaked {:monday [:banana :apple]
                     :sunday [:pineapple :mango]}); {:banana :monday
                                                     :apple  :monday
                                                     :pineapple :sunday
                                                     :mango     :sunday}
```

I hope that the question is well-defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could use list comprehension. like this:

```
(defn map-invert-tweaked [m]
  (into {} (for [[k vs] m
                 v vs]
             [v k])))
```

this `for` part does something like this:

```
var result = [];

for (var k in m) {
    var vs = m[k];
    for (var i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
        var v = vs[i]
        result.push([v, k]);
    }
}
```

and then it just puts all these pairs into a map

in repl:

```
user> (map-invert-tweaked {:monday [:banana :apple]
                           :sunday [:pineapple :mango]})
{:banana :monday, :apple :monday, :pineapple :sunday, :mango :sunday}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Join the Vowel Generation!

Yes, the above works, but it would be much easier to read with actual words as variable names:

```
(defn invert-keylist-map [keylist-map]
  (into {} 
    (for [ [curr-key  value-list]   keylist-map
            curr-value              value-list]
      [curr-value curr-key] )))
```

Even better is to use [Prismatic Schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) to describe the shape of the inputs & outputs like so:

```
(ns ...
  (:require [schema.core :as s] ))

(s/defn invert-keylist-map :- { s/Any s/Any }  ; result is a map of anything -> anything
  [keylist-map  :- { s/Any [s/Any] } ]  ; input is a map of anything -> list-of-anything
  (into {} 
    (for [ [curr-key  value-list]   keylist-map
            curr-value              value-list]
      [curr-value curr-key] )))
```